# How to use put command in tftp

Tags: unity, command-line, software-installation

How to use put command in tftp to send file to server host in that articular directory
 remotely ,

Answer (score 3):

`man tftp` will fill you in on its peculiarities but for a simple connect, put and quit, here's a simple example:

```
$ tftp server
tftp> put file /remote/directory
tftp> quit
```

`file` refers to a file in the local current working directory. You can specify longer paths but I would recommending just `cd`ing to the right place before you connect.

If you're struggling with encoding issues, run `binary` before you `put`.

Comment: How to use rlogin